# Trying to cancel an if statement

Tags: c#

I am looking in my code if connected user has insert or update permission, stated in the SQL Server. If user has INSERT permission, editing previously saved records in table in datagridview is disabled, and only adding new rows is enabled. And if user has both INSERT or UPDATE permission, user can edit any records in table. My code works great if user has only INSERT permision but if he has both insert and update, i dont know how to cancel that if loop.
Here is my code for CellBeginEdit:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string db2 = Text1;
            string user2 = Text2;
            string pass2 = Text3;
            string selected = this.ComboBox1.GetItemText(this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem);
            using (SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog =" + db2 + "; User ID =" + user2 + "; Password =" + pass2 + ""))
            {
                SqlConn.Open();
                SqlCommand SqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                SqlCommand SqlCmd3 = new SqlCommand();
                SqlCmd2.Connection = SqlConn;
                SqlCmd3.Connection = SqlConn;
                SqlCmd2.CommandText = "SELECT isnull(has_perms_by_name('" + db2 + ".dbo." + selected + "', 'OBJECT', 'INSERT'), 0)";
                SqlCmd3.CommandText = "SELECT isnull(has_perms_by_name('" + db2 + ".dbo." + selected + "', 'OBJECT', 'UPDATE'), 0)";
                Int32 number2 = (Int32)SqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar();
                Int32 number3 = (Int32)SqlCmd3.ExecuteScalar();
                if (number2 == 1)
                {
                    if (!dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
                    {
                        if (e.RowIndex < dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
                        {
                            if (AddedRowIndex != e.RowIndex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Not allowed to edit previous records!");
                                e.Cancel = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if ((number2 == 1) && (number3 == 1))
                {
                    //enable editing of all records in table
                }
                SqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is an _if loop_ ?

Comment: What's about `if ((number2 == 1) && (number3 != 1))` in your first if.

Comment: `if` statements do not loop. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/iteration-statements) is MSDN's documentation of iteration (loop) statements.

Comment: Am I blind or is there no iteration/iterative loops at all in the provided code?

Comment: Can't you just put a return statement there?

Comment: @Steve Oops sorry, my typing was quicker then my thinking :D Corrected title to ..if statement.

Comment: @Symon yeah i know, my mistake in typing.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen Thanks, if ((number2 == 1) && (number3 != 1)) worked. Have tried everything but this one. Consider this question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're checking for the more simple condition first, and it's going to be `true` for both Insert and Update, which means the `else if` condition is never checked and your enable-update code never runs.

Instead, you should check the compound condition first, and if that's false, *then* check the single condition.

For example:

```
if (number2 == 1 && number3 == 1)
{
    // enable editing of all records
}
else if (number2 == 1)
{
    // enable insert only
}
```

or another option, since they share a condition:

```
if (number2 == 1)
{
    if (number3 == 1)
    {
        // enable editing of all records
    }
    else
    {
        // enable insert only
    }
}
```